# What would theoretically be dissolved in the interior oceans of icy moons and planets?

Tags: planet, natural-satellites

I know we have some indication of "what's in the water" from the plumes of Enceladus, but would other places be the same. For instance, could the deep liquid water of Titan contain dissolved methane gas?

I'm mainly contemplating what possible "solutions" would be beneficial to some form of microbiology.

Comment: Isn't this a little broad? It sounds like it's more or less asking for a list of all substances that can be dissolved in subsurface oceans of unspecified salinity.

Comment: I totally agree with the comment above. It's been a while since I looked at this question. I guess I could slightly narrow the question to: What naturally occurring compounds could be dissolved in a subsurface ocean that could be used for energy production by microbiology as we know it. I fear this may still be too broad.

Comment: I'd be comfortable with that limited scope.

Answer (score 1):

There is no guarantee of solutions for life (known), but basically you need solutions of anions and cations, as [phosphates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phosphate) for building long chains as well as maintaining neutrality (acid and electronic equilibrium) weather, or any CHONSP (carbon, hydrogen, oxygen, nitrogen, sulfur, and phosphorus) with neutral acid (water) solution but this only applies for well known carbon life.